# Como pegar um objeto especifico de um array com varios objetos

Tags: javascript

Como eu posso buscar apenas um objeto dentro do array.

ex: tenho um json com 2 objeto

```
"urna": [
  {
    "partido": "Stark",
    "nomeCandidato": "Ned Stark",
    "numeroCandidato":["5", "4", "3", "2", "1"]
  },
  {
    "partido": "Casa Targaryen",
    "nomeCandidato": "Daenerys Targaryen",
    "numeroCandidato": ["6", "5", "4", "3", "2"]
  }
]
```

No meu service eu criei uma função para retornar os objetos do meu array "urna" tudo certinho, porém não estou conseguindo puxar os campos "partido" e  "nomeCandidato", de acordo com o  "numeroCandidato".

Eu estou fazendo um  forEach;

```
  this.urna = urna // this.urna é meu obj
    this.urna.forEach((urnaCandidato) => {
        urnaCandidato.nomeCandidato
    })
```

Porém estou trazendo todos os nomesCandidato, não estou conseguindo pensar em uma logica para trazer os campos "partido" e  "nomeCandidato" de acordo com numeroCandidato.

Comment: pesquiser por `filter` em javascript, deve ajudar, tem várias perguntas similares aqui no site

Answer (score -2):

Boa noite, usando o map é possível fazer isso;

veja no exemplo abaixo como usar o map para pegar um atributo específico do seu objeto no array.

```
let users = [
  {firstName : "Susan", lastName: "Steward"},
  {firstName : "Daniel", lastName: "Longbottom"},
  {firstName : "Jacob", lastName: "Black"}
];

let userFullnames = users.map(function(element){
    return `${element.firstName} ${element.lastName}`;
})

console.log(userFullnames);
```